# Does template location matter?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010

Does the location of a template matter to the resulting document?

In other words, is there a benefit to opening and using a Microsoft Word 2010 template from C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates rather than opening the file from say a shared directory?

I'm most concerned about file stability (crashing) and style formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If by resulting document you mean an existing document then no the location of the template doesn't matter at all, Microsoft Word only uses the template once off when when the document is first created.